# Not able to install marble and kpatience

Tags: games, kde-apps

I am trying to install two software:

1. Marble - a software for studying maps and globe and
2. KPatience - a card game.

Both seem to start the installation nicely but as the download progresses suddenly it stops asking me to check my Internet connection, which is fine. Both these software are part of some KDE package as I understood from their description.

I don't know much about that and I am a new user to Linux. Someone please help me with this problem. I am using Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: Did you try downloading after a while? Maybe it was some server side problem.

Comment: I tried many times after that. Also I tried it again after restarting the system and connection but still no use.

Comment: Please paste the messages that asks you to check your Internet connection. A few messages before it too.

Comment: Got this message while trying to install KPatience again- Failed to download package files-Check your Internet connection.-  Details-Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/q/qt4-x11/libqt4-qt3support_4.8.1-0ubuntu4.1_i386.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.181 80]

Comment: Also, try running "sudo apt-get update" and then installing the packages.

Comment: Thank you for the help I ran the update as u mentioned and the installations ran fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try running `sudo apt-get update` first and then do the installation.

Answer (score 0):

Long time ago the question, but I got the same problem in 2023 how I solved?

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install kpat
```

having some problems with snap and kpat

[here is where I found the solution](https://howtoinstall.co/en/kpat)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1287954)